# Recall that the "floor" of a real number $x$ , denoted $⌊x⌋$ , is the largest interger $\leq x$ .

Tags: probability

Recall that the "floor" of a real number  $x$ , denoted  $\lfloor x \rfloor$ , is the largest integer  $\leq x$ .

$$F(x)=  \begin{cases} k-\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}, & x \ge 1,\\ 0, & x \lt 1,\end{cases}$$  is a cummulative distribution function (cdf) for some fixed number  k . Find: k.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this question can someone give me any hint i know the formula of cumulative distribution function but don't know how to apply it one this question.

Comment: @Andrei  The OP is trying to do a "cases" and the edit needs one additional approval.

Comment: Please change your title to something more appropriate. 
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/) .

Comment: Ask yourself this: Can $k=2$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For an $F$ to represent a cumulative distribution, we should have that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$.